# C++ Is it possible to encrypt data sent over a named pipe?

Tags: c++, encryption, named-pipes

I have a named pipe server and a named pipe client that communicate with each other. But I don't want anyone to be able to read the data sent via the named pipe. The code is written in C++.

I have couple of questions:

1) is it possible at all tap into a named pipe?

2) if it is possible to tap into a named pipe, is it possible to encrypt data being sent via the named pipe?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend to use well known secure algorithms (AES for example) and libraries (WolfSSL or [OpenSSL](https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/EVP_Symmetric_Encryption_and_Decryption)) for encryption.

BTW, most of the current CPUs support HW acceleration for AES algorithm.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, it is possible. If you write both client and server side. Data over pipe is simply sequence of bytes. For compact algorithm, see XXTEA.